# Помощь в создании mp3 плеера

Tags: android-viewpager

В общем, есть ViewPager, 2 страницы(fragment). Вопрос - как сделать,  чтобы  при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице, на второй формировался  ListActivity. Делаю так:

```
//код кнопки(OnClick)
public void foll(View view){
    //list music = new list();
    ListView lvMain = ((ListView)marina.findViewById(R.id.lvMain));
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.mylist,data);
    lvMain.setAdapter(fileList);
}
```

Приложение выбивает ошибку

Comment: Напишите текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить что у вас в `xml` у кнопки прописано что-то типа `android:onClick="foll"`. Для фрагментов такое не работает, нужно найти кнопку и вручную назначить ей обработчик.

UPD. Чтобы из одного фрагмента вызвать второй можно проделать следующее:

```
    ListViewFragment fragment = (ListViewFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListViewTag");
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.someMethod();
    }
```

Где `ListViewFragment` - это ваш 2 фрагмент, `ListViewTag` это тег с которым вы его создали, `someMethod` - это публичный метод во 2 фрагменте которые делает то что вам надо, например заполняет `ListView`.

Comment: т.е из одного фрагмента, можно управлять элементами другого просто так?

Comment: @antonin14d обновил ответ